# Objects behind partial-transparent objects are masked out when selected

Tags: texturing, transparency

The setup:
Display/shade mode is Textured, Shading is Multitexture

No objects have materials, they're purely textured in the 3D view using the info assigned via UV/Image editor.  No objects have "Transparency" checked in the Properties panel/Object/Display pane, but when I've tried it has no effect for this issue.

Question: when selecting objects which are partly or fully overlapped by another object with a texture that is partly transparent, then when one of those objects are selected, the portion that is overlapped by the partially transparent object is entirely masked out.

Is there a way to more appropriately set this up before I get to using the materials?  Or can someone point me to a wiki/manual entry for this behaviour if it's the proper behaviour.  I've been searching for hours.

Pictures say more than words....

Clear plastic is selected, nothing disappears:
[image: Clear plastic is selected, nothing disappears]

Card backing selected and disappears behind plastic:
[image: Card backing selected and disappears behind plastic]

Action figure selected, upper body out of plastic, lower body disappears:
[image: Action figure selected, upper body out of plastic, lower body disappears]

Action figure and card backing selected, both disappear behind plastic:
[image: Action figure and card backing selected, both disappear behind plastic]

EXTRA UPDATE...

This is very weird.  If I grab the set of objects and duplicate and move them, then the viewport rendering weirdness reverses itself: the clear plastic is opaque when unselected; translucent when selected.  Further, if I repeatedly select the new created reversed-behaviour objects, duplicate and move, the behaviour reverses again so the clear plastic is translucent, but selecting the character within causes it to be clipped. And so I get something like this:
[image: alternating weird behaviour when repeated duplicating..]

Comment: I asked a similar question a couple years ago and no one had a solution that fixes this with a UI settings.  To me it looks like the draw order code for the OpenGL display is going wrong.  With transparency, typically objects should be drawn from back to front.  If objects are drawn out of order, we see this effect where transparent objects clip the objects that are supposed to be seen through the clear object.

Comment: @MarcClintDion ah thanks for the comment.  That OpenGL behavior is something I've run across in code experiments.  So maybe you think I will receive no effective help?  What about the second update to my question, any thoughts about the alternating behavior?

Comment: I tend to avoid transparency when using Blender or working on code for personal projects.  It's a bugeroo.  So far as what I am seeing in the image above.  Stating from the left: It looks like the character is being drawn first, then the box is drawn afterwards.  Because the character is drawn before the transparency, we can it when the package is drawn.  For the next set over.  It looks like the package is drawn first so there is no character info stored in the color buffer because it has not been drawn yet. (There's nothing to blend the alpha with when the package is drawn first.

Comment: There may be some settings that bypass or fix this problem.  Are you rendering in the viewport, Cycles or BI.... exporting?  
'Order Independent Transparency' is the buzz-word associated with solutions to this problem.   Here is a doc that explains this with images and fancy words.  http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2014/presentations/S4385-order-independent-transparency-opengl.pdf

Comment: @MarcClintDion Thanks, I'll check out that article.  My rendering is quite sadly limited (for the moment) to screen capturing the view from the 3D view, and cutting out any blender chrome.  That's primarily because I am not very comfortable/trained with blender rendering and recent good experience lighting.  These screen captures were from an exercise in modelling and texture painting, and composition. Composition was a challenge with the bug in the way.

Comment: I've been using this affect in preference to chroma key, and it can be removed altogether.  See here - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-is-an-inviso-mask-effect/74355#74355    Scroll down to the subheading - "To Be or Not to Be"