# My texture doesn't appear when placed under a transparent object

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to retexture a Community-Made model from the game *Team Fortress 2* called *the Bi-Decoder* (Google it- or Bing if you're *that* kind of person -if you don't know what it looks like. I can't link any more pictures.) The screen on the model is made of two parts. A transparent (but slightly translucent) material that gives the screen it's convex shape, and a layer underneath that has the actual contents of the screen mapped on to it. The screen's contents are supposed to look like this:

[image]

However, when I render the model, the Transparent layer is black and opaque!

[image: Sorry for the partially done UV mapping, btw.]

(Everything is set up to run in the Blender renderer, not Cycles.)

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you checked transparency on the object tab in the properties panel?

Comment: Yes, It's checked.

Comment: If you're rendering in OpenGL or viewing the model in the 3D viewport and the screen in the model has any level other than complete transparency in it's "Material" properties, you're experiencing what I call the 'Inviso' effect.  Anything behind it is liable to be rendered invisible!  Have a look here  - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/is-there-a-blender-alternative-to-chroma-key-rendering-in-opengl  for a working demo of this effect and how to defeat it.  I'm just about to edit that because I've since discovered an easier method to immunize other objects from it's effect.

Comment: Why do people insist on using blender internal. It's old and deprecated. I have no issues with cycles using transparency. I even use it to mimic glass.

Comment: I've tried cycles, too. It still doesn't work!